# PostgreSQL migrate from RHEL to SUSE

Tags: postgresql

I am currently working on migrating the PostgreSQL database from one system to another. My PostgreSQL Version 15 database runs on RHEL 9 and plans to migrate the database to a new system running on SUSE 15.

I was just trying to figure out, is it possible to restore the PostgreSQL database backup from pg_dump on RHEL 9 to the PostgreSQL database running on SLES 15.

Source System:
PostgreSQL Version: 15
Operating system : RHEL 9 64bit(x86)

Destination System:
PostgreSQL Version: 15
Operating system : SLES 15 64bit(x86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pg_dump/pg_restore will work just fine.

As you are switching the operating system you can not just copy the data directory.

If you have to minimize downtime you could think about using logical replication from the old server to the new, but that is not easy to setup. If the database isn't too big, pg_dump/pg_restore is probably easier to manage.

To fully migrate one instance (aka cluster) to another computer you either need to use `pg_dumpall` or (which I prefer) use `pg_dumpall` to only dump the "globals" (e.g. user accounts and roles) as a SQL script.

Then use `pg_dump/pg_restore` for each database individually.

Comment: What if the database version changes between source and destination system.

Source System: PostgreSQL Version: 14 Operating system : RHEL 9 64bit(x86)

Destination System: PostgreSQL Version: 15 Operating system : SLES 15 64bit(x86)

Comment: Then pg_dump/pg_restore is going to work as well [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html)